# Ordenar y sumar elementos

Tags: python, lista

soy nuevo en esto de python y tengo una duda resolviendo el siguiente ejercicio:
Se va a ingresar por teclado los siguientes datos; nombre de equipo, nombre de jugador, goles y asistencias. Mostrar cantidad de goles totales de cada equipo.
El ejercicio tiene mas consignas pero estoy bloqueado con esa, mi duda radica a modo de ejemplo en que, si n usuarios ingresan datos del mismo equipo como agrupo esos datos y sumo los goles y asistencias para poder mostrarlos por pantalla.

Por ejem:

usuario1 ingresa nome="a", goles=1

usuario2 ingresa nome="b", goles=2

usuario3 ingresa nome="a", goles=4

Utilizando el siguiendo codigo:

```
lista=[]
def cargar_datos(list):
    nome=raw_input("ingrese nombre del equipo o zzz para terminar ")
    while nome !="zzz":
        goles=input("ingrese cantidad de goles ")
        totales=goles
        for x in lista:
            if nome in x:
                totales=totales+x[1]
        lista.append([nome,goles,totales])
        nome=raw_input("ingrese nombre del equipo o zzz para terminar ")    
    return lista
cargar_datos([])
print lista
```

De salida obtengo:

> [["a",1,1],["b",2,2],["a",4,5]]

Y desearía tener de salida lo siguiente:

> [["a",5],["b",2]]

Puse ejemplos sencillos para tratar de ser lo mas claro posible, disculpen si no lo soy.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español!, 
te invito a que des este [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y veas cómo funciona este sitio. Si tienes dudas de como preguntar te recomiendo que 
revises [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
No basta con decir quiero esto o aquello, la idea es que compartas el código que has utilizado para intentar llegar a la solución.

Answer (score 4):

Si es solo para manejar esos dos datos, sale mucho más fácil trabajar con diccionarios. El índice del diccionario representará una entidad única (equipo o jugador) y su valor el dato acumulativo.

```
# Ejemplo para Python 2.x
lista = {}
nome = ""
while nome != "zzz":
    nome = raw_input("Ingrese el nombre del equipo o zzz para terminar: ")
    if nome != "zzz":
        goles = input("ingrese cantidad de goles: ")
        if nome in lista:
            lista[nome] += goles # Si el equipo esta en el dic, solo sumar los goles
        else:
            lista[nome] = goles # Si el equpo no existe en el dic, agregarlo

print lista
```

Un índice de un diccionario solo puede tener un valor referenciado, pero este valor también puede ser una lista u otro diccionario, así que si se pueden manejar más de un dato como valor.

```
lista = {'EQ_A':[3, 6], 'EQ_B':{'Juan Perez':[2, 4], 'tot_goles':8, 'tot_asist':6}}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, tu codigo me sirve para mostrar (equipo, goles totales). Recien estoy empezando a informarme sobre diccionarios que son del tipo (clave,valor). A partir de tu codigo voy a investigar 1 poco mas para obtener diferentes salidas. Con respecto a los datos ingresados por el usuario serian; nombre de equipo, nombre jugador, goles y asistencias.

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de qué otras cosas te puedan pedir, y de qué conocimientos se supone que puedes usar en tu pregunta, tienes diferentes alternativas a la hora de guardar los datos.

- Usar una lista en la que cada elemento contiene la información introducida por el usuario. Durante la primera parte del programa te limitas a ir metiendo esa información en la lista, sin hacer ningún cálculo, y después, una vez introducidos todos los datos, mediante bucles iteras por ellos para sumar todos los goles que correspondan a un equipo dado, o a un jugador dado, o a lo que se pida.

  Cada elemento de la lista anterior podría ser otra lista (o tupla) en la que, por ejemplo, el primer elemento es el nombre del equipo, el segundo elemento es el nombre del jugador y el tercer elemento es el número de goles. O también podría ser un diccionario cuyas claves sean "equipo", "jugador", "goles", por ejemplo.
- Usar un diccionarios. El diccionario "principal" tendría como clave el equipo. Cada elemento de ese diccionario sería otro diccionario cuyas claves serían los jugadores y los valores serían los goles de cada uno. Estos goles podrías ir actualizándolos mientras lees los datos, si te encuentras con que el equipo y jugador ya tenía un valor asignado para el número de goles (le sumarías el nuevo valor). De este modo al terminar la lectura ya tendrías la lista de equipos (serían las claves del diccionario) y para cada equipo la lista de jugadores (serían las claves del sub-diccionario) y los goles de cada jugador, que podrías sumar en un bucle para obtener los goles del equipo.
- Usar otras estructuras de datos más avanzadas (`namedtuple`, programación orientada a objetos, ...)

Ya que no has dado muchos detalles sobre qué mas cosas te piden, es difícil decidir de momento la solución más adecuada.

Por otro lado, ya que claramente se trata de una tarea académica y este no es sitio para resolver las tareas, sino sólo para responder a dudas concretas, me he limitado a darte ideas pero sin darte código. Intenta implementar alguna de ellas y cuando al hacerlo te aparezcan dudas concretas, crea una nueva pregunta.