# Python ejercicio de listas

Tags: python, lista

soy nuevo en esto de "programar" comencé la universidad y tengo una materia que se dedica a python quería pedir ayuda con el siguien ejercicio.

a) Realice una funcion que lea las estadisticas de partidos de basquet.
La informacion ingresada sera: equipo, fecha, nombre de jugador, cantidad de libres, cantidad de dobles, cantidad de triples. La carga de informacion finalizara cuando se ingrese como nombre de jugador el valor "ultimo". Al finalizar la carga se debera imprimir el nombre de cada equipo con el total de puntos en el campeonatos. Recordar, los libres valen 1 punto, los dobles 2 puntos y los triples 3 puntos.

Recien estoy empezando a ver lo de listas y tuplas pero no se como sumar los diferentes elementos de la lista. El codigo para cargar los datos.

```
ListaBasquet=[]

def cargar_datos(list):

    Equipo=raw_input("Ingresar nombre del equipo o ultimo para terminar ")

    while Equipo != "ultimo":

        Fecha=input("Ingresar fecha de partido ")

        Jugador=raw_input("Ingresar nombre de jugador ")

        Libres=input("Ingresar cantidad de libres ")

        Dobles=input("Ingresar cantidad de dobles ")

        Triples=input("Ingresar cantidad de triples ")

        ListaBasquet.append([Equipo,Fecha,Jugador,Libres,Dobles,Triples])

        Equipo=raw_input("Ingresar nombre del equipo o ultimo para terminar")

    return ListaBasquet

cargar_datos(ListaBasquet)

print ListaBasquet
```

Mi gran inconveniente es, si n usuarios ingresan datos del mismo equipo, como los acumulo y sumo para poder mostrarlos y tener de salida ("EQUIPOA", "TOTALDEPUNTOS"), ("EQUIPOB","TOTALDEPUNTOS").

Comment: Este enunciado es prácticamente idéntico al de [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/291418/7123) que también ha salido hoy. No sólo el enunciado, sino también la duda concreta del usuario ¿sois el mismo?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ordenar y sumar elementos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/291418/ordenar-y-sumar-elementos)